# Java deleteCharAt Function

Tags: java, string

I created this method deleteCharAt in order to remove a char from a string by its index:

```
public String deleteCharAt(String str, int i) {

    if (i == 0) {
        return str.substring(1);
    }
    else if (i == str.length()) {
        return str.substring(0, i-1);
    }

    String first = str.substring(0, i - 1);
    String second = str.substring(i+1);

    return first + second;
}
```

However it's not working as expected, I think it may be because I'm not understanding how the substring function works.

Does this look correct? Will this code remove the i-th character from a string successfully? Or did I mess up the substring function?

Comment: `Will this code remove the i-th character from a string successfully?` Well... how about just trying it out?

Comment: I did, but it seems like it deletes the correct one but also the one right before the correct one.

Comment: the way youre doing it is fine, but StringBuffer already has a method that does exactly what you are trying to do, if there is something out there that already exists for what you are trying to do, then dont "re-invent the wheel."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite right - this:

```
String first = str.substring(0, i - 1);
```

should be:

```
String first = str.substring(0, i);
```

(Think about a simple example - if `i` is 1, you want to take `substring(0, 1)` to get the first character; `substring(0, 0)` would give an empty string.)

because the second parameter of `substring` is already *exclusive*.

Likewise this optimization:

```
else if (i == str.length()) {
    return str.substring(0, i);
}
```

should be:

```
else if (i == str.length() - 1) {
    return str.substring(0, i);
}
```

You should also add argument validation.

After making those changes, this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(deleteCharAt("0123456789", i));
    }
}
```

Gives this output:

```
123456789
023456789
013456789
012456789
012356789
012346789
012345789
012345689
012345679
012345678
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String deleteCharAt(String s, int pos) {
   StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( s.length() - 1 );
   buf.append( s.substring(0,pos) ).append( s.substring(pos+1) );
   return buf.toString();
}
```